# How to read one line then jumps three, while in pandas.read_csv(), until the end of the text file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a text file with nexto to 8000 thousand rows  ([like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYenm.png)). But I only need to read some of the rows of the file (marked in red in the image), with the pandas.read_csv() function.

The logic I'm trying to do is like: "read one line, then jumps three" until the end of the file, so I won't use the rows that are useless for me.

I know that there is the parameter `skiprows=`in the `pd.read_csv()`  function, but I'm not sure how to *pythonly* put the logic in the parameter of the function. In the end, I will need a dataframe with **only** the following columns, of all the text file:

```
header = ["Elm Ion","WL_air(A)","log gf*","E_low(eV)", "Waals"]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use python's csv module instead for more granular control. If you are working on a unix machine, you could probably use `grep` to filter the rows; I'd expect it to be fast/efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @sammywemmy's comment about csv module for more granular control, it will make things WAY easier to modify and customize. That said, the callable option did intrigue me, so here is how you could do it. (Note that we have to add edge cases to pick up the column header and first row.)

```
>>> def skip_func(x):
...     if x in (0, 1):
...         return False
...     else:
...         return (x-1) % 4 != 0

>>> pd.read_csv(filepath, skiprows=skip_func)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked incredibly well. I'm not used to python csv module, and this was a "small" work, so thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Pandas, and Python's CSV module is more than adequate for this job.

Also, you asked how to skip a certain number of lines, and my solution show just that.  ***But*** looking at your data, I see one row of "data" followed by some other meta-data rows (summary?), and that presents another way to think about your problem.

Here's the fixed-skip solution, and I'll go over the "relative skip" solution after that.

### Fixed skip, or skip n-lines/rows

Given this file, **input.csv**:

```
id,foo
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
5,e
6,f
7,g
8,h
9,i
10,j
```

when I run this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv

csv_out = open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(csv_out)

csv_in = open('input.csv', newline='')
reader = csv.reader(csv_in)

writer.writerow(next(reader))  # if your input CSV has a header

# Loop over rows
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)

    try:
        # next(reader) advances the CSV one row at a time; discard results
        next(reader)
        next(reader)
        next(reader)
    except StopIteration:
        # The expected exception when reader runs out of rows
        break
    except Exception as e:
        # Unexpected, raise it to user's attention
        raise e


csv_in.close()
csv_out.close()
```

I get this for **output.csv**:

```
id,foo
1,a
5,e
9,i
```

If you want to make the skip programmable:

```py
...
SKIP_ROWS = 3
...
for row in reader:
    try:
        for i in range(SKIP_ROWS):
             next(reader)
    except StopIteration:
    ....
```

### Relative skip, or skip rows with certain attributes

If the number of meta-data rows ever changes, skipping a fixed number of rows will break.  You might be better off skipping rows by their attributes.

The big distinction between the data and meta-data rows, that I see, is that a data row has many fields (columns) and a metadata row is a single field.

```py
...
for row in reader:
    if len(row) == 1:  # single column, or some other "attribute" of a row you want to skip
        continue       # skip it

    # process your real data
    ...
```

Comment: Well.... This is a lot more complex than i thought. Since I'm not used to python csv module I stuck to @Maksim answer's. But I want to learn more about this module, so I truly think your answer will help me. So... Thanks!

Comment: Cool, please vote it up if it does help.

Comment: Oh, I voted up, but I think I do not have enough reputation for this to work